# Android Devices Unable to Consume REST Service on Wifi

Tags: android, iphone, rest, xamarin

Hello there long time reader of Stack Overflow but first time poster,

I am a bit new to android development but we decided to build a Xamarin.Forms app which consumes our ASP.NET REST service. When running the app on an emulator on my computer, connected via ethernet, I am able to connect to the service. However, when running on a tablet or phone that is connected on our work wifi, the connection just hangs and times out.

Interesting enough, when the device is switched to mobile data it can connect to the endpoints again, and iPhones can connect to the endpoints on mobile data or wifi.

I'm curious what I'm missing here. Please let me know what you think or additional information I should include.

Comment: Have you checked for basic connectivity issues using the browser of the device?  Are you using the IP or FQDN for the server?  Is this a local server?  If it only hangs when using the work wifi, I'd guess that it's a local networking issue in your office.

Comment: Hey Jason: yeah we've tested out basic connectivity with both the silk browser, google chrome, and safari on the ios devices. When connecting we are using the FQDN, and our server is local. IPhones can connect to the services even when they're on our wifi though, so wouldn't it be something else?

Comment: Are you actually getting a timeout exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this thread has been opened for some time, we have found our problem resolved: it was a mixture of our network support changing some settings on our routers (though I can unfortunately not remember what settings) and also our tablets do a system update.

I am not sure which of these factors was the cause of our success now but the issue is done. I just wanted to post this in case anyone else ran into something similar.